# Setting Body of caught error in Middleware asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have followed the following link;

[Custom HttpResponseException Middleware Asp.Net Core 2.0](https://devblog.dymel.pl/2016/06/29/asp-net-core-status-code-empty-response/)

I now want to add a message to the body of the response to give context to the exception.

I modified the middleware Invoke method as follows;

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (HttpStatusCodeException exception)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)exception.StatusCode;
            // byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exception.Message);
            // await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(exception.Message);
            context.Response.Headers.Clear();
        }
    }
```

However when adding the WriteAsync line to the method I don't get a response from the Api (I am testing through postman).

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong here please?

Full code for the class and middleware are below;

```
namespace Services.WebApi.Middleware
{
    public class HttpErrorHandlerMiddleware
    {

        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public HttpErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (HttpStatusCodeException exception)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)exception.StatusCode;
                // byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exception.Message);
                // await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(exception.Message);
                context.Response.Headers.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class HttpErrorHandlerMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseHttpErrorHandlerMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<HttpErrorHandlerMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

The HttpStatusCodeException class is as follows;

```
    public class HttpStatusCodeException : Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }

    public HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message) : base(message)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hope this [link](https://www.billbogaiv.com/posts/using-aspnet-cores-middleware-to-modify-response-body) will help you to some extent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync(exception.Message);
context.Response.Headers.Clear();
```

Is not going to work, because after you sent the respose (via `Response.WriteAsync`) - headers cannot be changed\cleared, because headers are sent before the response body, and so at this moment are already sent to client. Just change the order like this:

```
context.Response.Headers.Clear();
await context.Response.WriteAsync(exception.Message);
```

And it should work as expected. It also worth checking that response has not already started at this point:

```
if (!context.Response.HasStarted) {
    context.Response.Headers.Clear();
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(exception.Message);
}
```

Also ensure that you register your middleware *before* other middleware. Right:

```
app.UseHttpErrorHandlerMiddleware();
app.UseMvc();
```

Wrong

```
app.UseMvc();
app.UseHttpErrorHandlerMiddleware();
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you for your help on this and the last question. I'd also like to say your explanations are also tip top and explain the situation well.